# C++ parsing file into an array of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, opencl

I'm trying to read a file in C++ and parse it into an array of structures. I kind of have this working. I can print the contents of the line that I am currently parsing/have parsed and it correctly prints to the console however, when iterating over the array (once it's been populated with the values gotten from the file) it prints nonsense.

I have a file that has contents similar to the line below:

`CONINGSBY 2015 11 26 2300 8.4`

So, I have created the struct below to hold the data

```
typedef struct WeatherDataStruct {
    const char* locationName;
    unsigned int year; // Year shouldn't be negative... We didn't have the tech back then...
    unsigned char month; // Month doesn't need to be a massive number since, we only have 12 of them...
    unsigned char day; // Same as month. Can only be 0-31
    unsigned int time; // 24 hour format. So, not going to be negative and an int should suffice.
    long airTemp; // Temp on the day. In celsius
};
```

I first get the number of lines from the file which, is then used to create a new array of the above structure. I then pass this newly created array and lines to a function. The function opens a stream to read the file. I then have the below while loop to parse the file.

```
    while (std::getline(_file, currentLine)) {
        std::stringstream iss(currentLine);

        std::string name, sYear, sMonth, sDay, sTime, sTemp;
        if (std::getline(iss, name, ' ') &&
            std::getline(iss, sYear, ' ') &&
            std::getline(iss, sMonth, ' ') &&
            std::getline(iss, sDay, ' ') &&
            std::getline(iss, sTime, ' ') &&
            std::getline(iss, sTemp, ' ')) {

            std::cout << "Name: " << name.c_str() << "\t";

            // Convert the strings into usable data
            unsigned int year = std::stol(sYear),
                time = std::stol(sTime);
            unsigned char month = static_cast<unsigned char>(std::stol(sMonth)),
                day = static_cast<unsigned char>(std::stol(sDay));
            long temp = std::stol(sTemp);

            weatherArray[i++] = { name.c_str(), year, month, day, time, temp };
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Error reading file \"" << filename << "\": Couldn't parse file. It doesn't follow the format given. Line: " << i << std::endl;
        }
        //std::cout << std::endl;
        percent = ((double)i / (double)totallines) * 100;
        printf("\r%.2f%%", percent);
    }
```

The output of the console while parsing is what I expect, I see the "name" printed. All's good. The problem occurs when trying to read the "locationName" property of any element inside the new array. Both VS debugger and the console can't read the strings.

```
    std::cout << "DATA:\n\t[";

    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        printf("%s|%d, ", weatherArray[i].locationName, weatherArray[i].airTemp);
        //std::cout << weatherArray[i].locationName << "|" << weatherArray[i].airTemp << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "\b\b]" << std::endl;
```

Array in debug window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI8Oi.png

Output in console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvwoQ.png

Note: Changing the data in the structure to `std::string` works however, I read somewhere that OpenCL doesn't like strings (I want to be able to send an array of the structure to a kernel and do some parallel magic).

Edit:

Thanks to @JustinRandall for the information. I fixed this problem by changing the struct definition to the following:

```
typedef struct WeatherDataStruct {
    char locationName[60] = "Default value";
    unsigned int year; // Year shouldn't be negative... We didn't have the tech back then...
    unsigned char month; // Month doesn't need to be a massive number since, we only have 12 of them...
    unsigned char day; // Same as month. Can only be 0-31
    unsigned int time; // 24 hour format. So, not going to be negative and an int should suffice.
    long airTemp; // Temp on the day. In celsius

    WeatherDataStruct() {}

    WeatherDataStruct(std::string name, unsigned int year, unsigned char month, unsigned char day, unsigned int time, long temp) {
        strcpy_s(locationName, name.c_str());
        this->year = year;
        this->month = month;
        this->day = day;
        this->time = time;
        this->airTemp = temp;
    }

};
```

Comment: You can't populate a `const char *` like that. You need to use `strcpy` or a loop to populate each character.  `std::string` worked for you because it supports assignment by `=`. Also if you're doing it that way you need to allocate memory.  It's probably easier to have a fixed sized array i.e `const char locationName[80]` or however big your max size locationName will be.

Comment: In your data structure you can replace `const char* locationName` simply with `std::string locationName`. And that will prevent you from having to allocate memory for a `char*` - `char[const size]`.

Comment: @JustinRandall Aha! Thank you. I managed to fix this issue by changing the struct definition.

Comment: Why `unsigned char`. It takes the same size as `unsigned int` when in a struct, and you ought to write the validation logic anyway.

Comment: @Joker_vD does it? I didn't know that... I thought it would be the same as normal (int being 4 bytes and char being 1 byte)